How to render a ball into an 360° image

Hey, I want to render the ball shown in the image as a 360° image.
My Plan is to have the camera like a cylinder facing inwards.
So any objects on top of the ball, are also being included (like the cube)
Does anyone know how to do this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Very similar goal:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/89719/45359
